# Is it possible to return 500 error code with a custom error page in nginx

Tags: nginx, routes, rules, http-status-code-500

I have a custom error page which I use by rewrite directive in nginx. I want to return 500 error code while rendering this error page. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with a config like this one, which will serve the file at `/usr/share/nginx/html/err_500.html`.

```
server {

    ...

    error_page 500 /err_500.html;
    location = /err_500.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
}
```

You can check out [this guide from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-22-04) for more in-depth instructions on making custom error pages with Nginx.

To make this page appear, all you need to do is trigger a response with status code 500, which you can do from a reverse-proxied application or from nginx itself, as shown below

```
location /errorme {
    return 500;
}
```